# How do I make a LDAP query-based dynamic distribution group in Exchange 2010

Tags: ldap, exchange-2010, distribution-lists

I see that there were ways in Exchange 2003 and Exchange 2007 to just put in an LDAP query and it would populate the group for you. Is there any way to do that in Exchange 2010?

I know there's dynamic distribution groups but I don't want to create the group based on one of their pre-set queries and I don't want to mess around with "custom attributes".  I just want to put an LDAP query in there and make it run it to populate the distribution group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecipientFilter` flag of the `New-DynamicDistributionGroup` and `Set-DynamicDistributionGroup` commands gives you the same flexibility of raw LDAP filtering.

Here's Microsoft's example from the command's [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125127.aspx):

`New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "Pacific Northwest" -Alias "Pacific_Northwest" -OrganizationalUnit "contoso.com/Users" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and ((StateOrProvince -eq 'Washington' -or StateOrProvince -eq 'Oregon')))} -RecipientContainer "contoso.com"`